# Ordered Dictionary python replace key value

Tags: python, dictionary

```
a = OrderedDict([(14, (2361.42, 1339.25)), (15, (3581.08, 1427.08)), (16, (0, 4640.11)), (17, (0, 2667.36)), (18, (0, 1686.63))])

b =  OrderedDict([(14, '03-31'), (15, '04-07'), (16, '04-14'), (17, '04-21'), (18, '04-28')])
```

I want to replace the value in b, to a value along with b value
I have tried this

```
dict((b[key], value) for (key, value) in a.items())
```

the out put is

```
{'03-31': (2361.42, 1339.25), '04-07': (3581.08, 1427.08), '04-28': (0, 1686.63), '04-21': (0, 2667.36), '04-14': (0, 4640.11)}
```

I want it as

```
OrderedDict([('03-31', (2361.42, 1339.25)), ('04-07', (3581.08, 1427.08)), (04-14', (0, 4640.11)), ('04-21', (0, 2667.36)), ('04-28', (0, 1686.63))])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `OrderedDict` constructor instead:

```
OrderedDict((b[key], value) for (key, value) in a.items())
```